# JSONParser fails while parsing very large numbers

Tags: java, json

I am using org.json.simple.parser JSON Parser. One specific data contained very large numbers. For example it once failed while parsing a line with this error

java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "982134839798321390034432432"

Clearly it should be parsed with BigInt data type. Or there should be an option to treat these just as strings. What can be done in this case?

Comment: I guess it's called simple parser for a reason. Maybe you can just switch to a less simple library?

Comment: what is the json structure? is the number added as string (within quotes "") or as number?

Comment: Start by using a more standard and still supported library.

Comment: @Optional number added as a number itself, not enclosed in double quotes

Comment: @wvdz It would be of great help to suggest some names of such libraries than be sarcastic

Comment: I wasn't being sarcastic. Just thinking the name fits the description. This one works for me: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20170516

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue in "[json-simple](https://code.google.com/archive/p/json-simple/)", see https://github.com/fangyidong/json-simple/issues/73

You need to either:

1. Switch to a different JSON parser, for example https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson
2. Apply the patch on issue #73 to a private fork of "json-simple" and use that instead of the released version, or use "loegering"s fork at https://cliftonlabs.github.io/json-simple/ (linked from [issue #73](https://github.com/fangyidong/json-simple/issues/73))